# extJS - when-to & when-not to use square brackets

Tags: extjs, square-bracket

i have been learning extJS, and i could cram it up but i want to understand...

in the following cases we use square brackets, if not it gives error

```
require     : ['Ext.container.Viewport']
controllers : ['Users','List']
```

but in these we don't

```
Ext.define('myapplication.controller.Mycontroller',{.....
xtype  : 'panel'
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets means that it's an array (basic javascript). Your require array only contains 1 item now, but it can contain more items. Your controllers is an array of 2 items.

In your define example xtype doesn't expect an array but a string. Same with extend, you can only extend from one component.

This info can be found in the docs of ExtJS aswell. For example the controllers config from your example above:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-controllers

The docs mention this `controllers : String[]`. Which means it expects an array of strings.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that all this information is in the documentation.